# convert EditText to float - android eclipse

Tags: java, android

I want to convert `EditText` to float. I do this:

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
float number = Float.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
```

the app not load in my device and the simulator too. in both of them write:

```
"the application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again."
```

If I remove this line:

```
float number = Float.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
```

the app can load.

What can I to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be `edt.getText().toString()` is not returning a value that can turned into a float. Try putting the following around your code

`

```
float number = 0;
try{
   number = Float.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`
That should give you a clue why its dying.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a `Number` in the `EditText` you can't convert it to a float and you'll get a `NumberFormatException`.

So add a try-catch around the `Float.valueOf` method.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your app crashes because you try to convert the contents of the EditText to a float when the app has just started. At this point, the EditText is probably empty, or filled with some default text you set in the layout file, which can result in a `NullPointerException` or `NumberFormatException`.

Try getting the float value in a TextWatcher:

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float number = Float.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the value of the `EditText` right after the Application opens, this means there is nothing entered, the Application throw a `NumberFormatException`.

You only should get the values entered in the `EditText`, when you are sure there is somehthing entered, for example in the `OnClick` event of a `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

`edt` must contain text, and each character in the text must be a digit or a decimal point.  Especially note that empty string, "", does not represent 0. It cannot be interpreted as a Float value so will cause an exception.  Only "0", "0.0" etc can be interpreted as zero.

You should test the value of `edt` before you get the value and, `catch` the `Exception` properly.  You should also set the `inputType` of `edt` to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
float number=   Float.parseFloat(edt.getText().toString());
```